# How to start nvidia x server settings from command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, I know I can start NVIDIA x server settings by choose :

**System -> Preference -> Monitors**

on the top bar.

But how can I start the NVIDIA x server settings window by run a command from terminal? What is that command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it is:

```
   nvidia-settings
```